# Creating a subquery in MS Access while using AVG?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I create a subquery after averaging time by age? I want to make the ages as one group '20-29' with an overall average of that age group

```
SELECT [PAT Data].Gender, [PAT Data].Age, Avg([PAT Data].CourseTime) AS AvgOfCourseTime
FROM [PAT Data]
GROUP BY [PAT Data].Gender, [PAT Data].Age
HAVING ((([PAT Data].Gender)="F") AND (([PAT Data].Age)>="20" And ([PAT 
Data].Age)<="29"))


UNION

SELECT [PAT Data].Gender, [PAT Data].Age, Avg([PAT Data].CourseTime) AS 
AvgOfCourseTime
FROM [PAT Data]
GROUP BY [PAT Data].Gender, [PAT Data].Age
HAVING ((([PAT Data].Gender)="F") AND (([PAT Data].Age)>="30" And ([PAT 
Data].Age)<="39"))

UNION

SELECT [PAT Data].Gender, [PAT Data].Age, Avg([PAT Data].CourseTime) AS 
AvgOfCourseTime
FROM [PAT Data]
GROUP BY [PAT Data].Gender, [PAT Data].Age
HAVING ((([PAT Data].Gender)="F") AND (([PAT Data].Age)>="40" And ([PAT 
Data].Age)<="49"));
```

[This is how it looks when run currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gycGF.png)

Comment: Don't use the `mysql` tag for Access questions.

Comment: `GROUP BY Gender, FLOOR(Age/10)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch()`:

```
SELECT SWITCH(Age >= 20 And Age <= 29, "20-29",
              Age >= 30 And Age <= 39, "30-49",
              Age >= 40 And Age <= 49, "40-59",
              "Other") as agegrp,
       Gender,  Avg([PAT Data].CourseTime) AS AvgOfCourseTime
FROM [PAT Data]
WHERE [PAT Data].Gender) = "F"
GROUP BY [PAT Data].Gender,
         SWITCH(Age >= 20 And Age <= 29, "20-29",
                Age >= 30 And Age <= 39, "30-49",
                Age >= 40 And Age <= 49, "40-59",
                "Other") ;
```

Comment: Are those closing brackets in the wrong place after `Age`? Shouldn't they be after `<=29`?

Comment: I was wrong - after being able to check it should be either `Switch([Age]>=20 And [Age]<=29,"20-29",[Age]>=30 And [Age]<=49,"30-49",[Age]>=40 And [Age]<=59,"40-59",[Age]<20 Or [Age]>59,"Other")` **or** `Switch([Age]<20,"Other",[Age]<=29,"20-29",[Age]<=49,"30-49",[Age]<=59,"40-59",[Age]>59,"Other")`.  The second way works because it returns the first value that equates to TRUE.

Comment: And the bracket on the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    [PAT Data].Gender, 
    10*Fix([PAT Data].[Age]/10) AS AgeGroup, 
    Avg([PAT Data].Coursetime) AS AvgTime
FROM 
    [PAT Data]
WHERE 
    [PAT Data].Gender = "F"
GROUP BY 
    [PAT Data].Gender, 10*Fix([PAT Data].[Age]/10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer division by "\" and simple concatenation:

```
SELECT 
    10 * (Age \ 10) & "-" & 10 * (Age \ 10) + 9 As AgeGroup,
    Gender,  
    Avg(CourseTime) As AverageCourseTime
FROM 
    [PAT Data]
WHERE 
    Gender = "F"
GROUP BY 
    10 * (Age \ 10) & "-" & 10 * (Age \ 10) + 9
```

If you wish a minimum age:

```
WHERE 
    Gender = "F",
    Val(Age) >= 20
```

And do store Age as an integer number, not text. If number, then:

```
WHERE 
    Gender = "F",
    Age >= 20
```